# Changing the Moderation State Control Box input to a textarea

Tags: forms, 9

I wanted to change the moderation state control box input to a textarea like the image below shows. Currently the input only supports 128 characters but I believe log messages can hold much more in the database.

[image: Moderation control input]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve it with a hook. We can add the below PHP to a custom module. Make sure to change the name of `MYMODULE` below.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_content_moderation_entity_moderation_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  // Change log message input to textarea on content moderation control boxes.
  $form['revision_log'] = [
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#title' => t('Log message'),
  ];
}
```